# Electrum transaction using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, bitcoin

Hi i would like to send transactions to desired addresses. Since i launch my electrum wallet with ./electrum-3.3.8-x64 command and following the man page i came up with something like this:

```
./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage -w /home/.electrum/wallets/wallet_with_segwit payto address amount
```

But the following command returns:

```
Type 'electrum create' to create a new wallet, or provide a path to a wallet with the -w option
```

Is it possible what i want to reach? And how do you specify the amount to pay(BTC,USD)?

Edit1:

as in man page you can only pay in BTC:

```
amount              Amount to be sent (in BTC). Type '!' to send the
                    maximum available.
```

and after further checking i found:

```
 ./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage payto -w /home/.electrum/wallets/wallet_with_segwit -W passwd address amount
```

but still i got same error...

Answer (score 0):

In terminal you need to start Electrum daemon at first, then load a wallet, then make your transaction:

```
./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage daemon start
./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage load_wallet -w /home/.electrum/wallets/wallet_with_segwit
./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage payto <address> <btc_amount>
```